# Copy multiple sheets to one single sheet based on the sheet's content in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook which contains more than 50 sheets. I need to copy every sheet that contains "Seasoned Passthrough OAS" and paste it to the sheet whose name is "BC-Summary". How can I achieve this by VBA?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, not sure what all you'd want to copy to the summary so I just used a2-z100.

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "BC-Summary" Then
    Set cFind = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Seasoned Passthrough OAS", After:=ws.Range("A1"), LookIn:= _
                xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
                xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not cFind Is Nothing Then

        ws.Range("A2:Z100").Copy
        Sheets("BC-Summary").Range("A" & Sheets("BC-Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If

End If

Next ws

End Sub
```